# Joomla 1.5. CSS in left side Menu (Separator & articles)

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

On the next page: http://www.simbios.com/mombaers-verbeke-law/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=31&Itemid=134 . I want to add 2 different styles of font type and color in the left menu. One is a separator (eg Vennoten) and the other is an article (eg Sylvain Vandersteen). As I can have two different styles (color, font, etc.) to apply to a separator, and the other applies to the article, so that one has the white (article) and the other blue (separator). I have not found a way to differentiate them on the page in joomla application.

NOTE: I have a style sheet, but only refers to everything that is within that side of the left menu, because when I generated the separator or the article, not allow me to determine which style I can apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your *Left Menu Module* and add a **Module Suffix.** Add CSS styling in your stylesheet called

```
.leftMenuXXX {
color: blue !important;
font-family: xxxx !important;
}
```

Then in your new module, which is a replication of the current Left Menu, add `leftMenuXXX` to the Module Suffix, with a space in front.

Then you can adjust where the menu appears within the module, i.e. only appears on the pages you want it to change the font color and family.

Obviously, you will have to change the Left Menu to NOT appear on the page as the Left Menu Copy.

There are other ways of doing it, this is one of them..

It would be alot easier in Joomla 1.6+ because it has better module position definitions.